# Android SQLite core functions

Tags: android, sqlite

According to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) it has full sqlite support. Does it mean that I can use [core functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) as part of `projection` for query, like this:

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();    
final String [] projection = new String []{
    ...,
    ...,
    "replace(...) as replacedCol"
};

Cursor c = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

This snippet throws `IllegalArgumentException` (*Invalid column replace*(...)).
So is there way to use core functions in sqlite queries?

**edit** the error is likely to be caused by ContentProvider, which checks for allowed columns, so it seems that using functions with content resolver is impossible.

Comment: so it's impossible ... but ... assuming that youre using listview/spinner you can buid your custom adapter and replace this string there before setting to view (in getView or bindView)

Comment: @Selvin nope, it's ContactsContract provider

Comment: @Selvin yes, it seems to be the option. what's bothering me is i was going to use replaced column in `WHERE` clause, so replacing it in adapter is very likely to be inefficient. thanks for your help =)

Comment: did you tried ? i just look at ContactsProvider and SQLiteQueryBuilder source and i think that they didn't using projection there(i mean in selection argument(WHERE))

Comment: thank you so much, i totally missed i could use replace() in selection instead of projection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

projection in provider query <> columns in sql query

usually ContentProvider contains

```
static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
  map.put("NameInProjection", "RealDBColumn AS NameInProjection");
  map.put("replacedCol", "replace(...) as replacedCol");
}
```

and in query method of ContentProvider we use it like

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
  SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
  builder.setTables(table);
  builder.setProjectionMap(map);
  return builder.query(mDB.getReadableDatabase(), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
}
```

so SQLiteQueryBuilder translate projection to real query using the map